# Поиск удачного решения по обработке ошибок

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

В разрабатываемом приложении часть классов спроектированы таким образом, что статус выполнения функции либо возвращается, либо сохраняется в соответствующем поле. Эти классы связаны с обработкой файлов, xml-документов и т.п. После выполнения каждой операции приходится проверять статус выполнения, например:

```
if (xmlParser.hasError()) {
    log(...);
    return <ошибка выполнения>; // завершаем выполнение текущей функции, поскольку продолжать не имеет смысла.
}
```

Таких проверок в теле функции может набежать довольно много. Собственно вопрос: есть ли возможность уменьшить код, направленный на проверку статуса выполнения, и сосредоточиться на непосредственно логике самой функции. Возможно, лучше будет использовать тогда исключения? Либо текущее решение вполне жизнеспособно?

Comment: Исключения, IMHO, вполне можно использовать. И текущий подход можно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте исключения, они специально придуманы для этой цели.

Либо, при возникновении ошибки переводите `xmlParser` в состояние, когда он ничего не делает, и приверяйте ошибку один раз после всех операций с ним, как это сделано в стандартных потоках ввода-вывода:

```
void f(std::istream& s, int& a, int& b) {
  s >> a >> b;
  bool eof = !s;
  ...
```

Текущий подход к проверке ошибок плох тем, что он никак не поощряет и не контролирует то, что все ошибки будут проверены. Очень легко не написать этот `if (xmlParser.hasError())`, или например по ошибке написать `if (!xmlParser.hasError())`.

Если использовать возврат ошибок, то лучше возвращать ошибку из самой функции, которая выполняет действие приводящее к ошибке:

```
void parse(error_code& ec) {
  if (xmlParser.parse(ec))
    return;
}
```

либо можно использовать [монады](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/BestPracticeHandbook#a8.DESIGN:Stronglyconsiderusingconstexprsemanticwrappertransporttypestoreturnstatesfromfunctions) (в т.ч. optional), что является более современным подходом, но к сожалению пока мало библиотек реализующих типы `Result`, [`std::expected`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf) и т.п.

```
Result<void> result = xmlParser.parse();
if (!result)
  return result.error();
```

Answer (score 4):

Исключения. Если библиотека не умеет исключения, то пишем враппер для всех вызовов или что-то вроде:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void check_error(T &clazz, void (T::*method)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    (clazz.*method)(args...);
    if (clazz.hasError())
        throw runtime_error("Some error");
}
```

И звать как-то так:

```
check_error(f, &Foo::foo1);
check_error(f, &Foo::foo2, 31337);
```

У себя в проекте использовал `std::error_code`, переменная для его сохранения была опциональной, по умолчанию - специальное значение, если оно, то бросается исключение, если отлично - то сохраняется код ошибки. При таком подходе лень стимулирует не проверять код, но если что навернётся, сразу выпадет исключение. Выглядит как-то так:

```
void setCodec(const Codec &codec, bool resetDefaults, std::error_code &ec = throws());
...
void CodecContext::setCodec(const Codec &codec, bool resetDefaults, error_code &ec)
{
    clear_if(ec); // очистка предыдущего кода ошибки

    if (!m_raw)
    {
        fflog(AV_LOG_WARNING, "Codec context does not allocated\n");
        throws_if(ec, Errors::Unallocated);
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Но эта библиотека, сама по себе враппер. Детали `throws()`, `clear_if()`, `throws_if()` можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp/blob/master/src/averror.h) и [тут](https://github.com/h4tr3d/avcpp/blob/master/src/averror.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

Данное решение вполне жизнеспособно, не раз встречалось мне в разного масштаба проектах. Ближайший пример библиотека работы с zip от Nokia - там десяток (если не больше) подобных вызовов на различных стадиях распаковки/чтения файлов/zip заголовков.

Comment: Ну давайте тогда подеремся по такому прекрасному поводу )

Comment: @Abyx ну зачем сарказм, вы же можете сразу конструктивно возразить )

Answer (score 1):

Вы могли бы разнести данную часть кода

```
if (xmlParser.hasError()) {
    log(...);
    return <ошибка выполнения>; // завершаем выполнение текущей функции, поскольку продолжать не имеет смысла.
}
```

по отдельным фрагментам функций.

Например, вызов

```
    log(...);
```

можно было бы поместить в те функции, которые выполняют соответствующие операции. Эту запись в журнал событий можно сделать зависимой от наличия заданных в начале работы программы условий.

В самом же классе сделать явный оператор приведения к типу `bool`, значение объекта которого было бы равно наличию или отсутствию ошибки.

Например,

```
explicit operator bool() const { return !hasError(); }
```

Тогда ваш код мог бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
while ( xmlParser )
{
    // выполнение обработки
}
```

И, соответственно, ответственность за запись ошибок в журнал лежал бы на вызываемых функциях, а не на клиентском коде.

Также вы могли бы включить установку, которая сообщает, нужно ли выбрасывать исключение при возникновении ошибки.

То есть я вам хочу предложить тот же самый подход, который реализован в стандартных потоках ввода-вывода.